# MEAN stack app - Getting 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' error after deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku, mean-stack

The MEAN stack app is working fine on local environment, but I'm getting 
'`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`' error after deploying on Heroku. 
**The app can be found here:**
https://ai-product-review-v1.herokuapp.com/

**And the code is here:**
https://github.com/SaurabhBorse/ai-product-review-v1

Here is the screenshot from debug console. 
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: There is definitely an unclosed tag in one of your components. Check the output of the angular build process. Let me look at the project.

Comment: please wait for 5 minutes, I am updating the code

Comment: @IkennaAnthonyOkafor The code has been updated, you can check it now. https://github.com/SaurabhBorse/ai-product-review-v1

Comment: It's working now. Removing /public/js/ from .gitignore files solved the issue. Thank you for your reply mate.

Comment: Ok, good to go then.